# How to hide a part of my UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have few other UI in my UIView and i have a UIButton on the top which i want to be hidden until unless the user scrolls to see the content on the very top and then display the UIButton.
Is there a way to implement this.

Thanks,

Comment: Can't you just put your button at the top of the view - then when the user scrolls it into view, they will see it?

Comment: but when the view gets displayed i want it to be hidden and when user scrolld down i want it to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

UIView (and thus everything sub-classing it) has a hidden property, this includes a UIButton. You can simply set this to YES/NO to hide/show something to the user.

After that the real question comes down to the show/hide criteria and how to measure it. If you are using a UIScrollView then you can add/implement `UIScrollViewDelegate`. This will give you methods like `scrollViewDidScrollToTop:` to check if the user scrolled to the top.

Comment: This delegate method is not getting called, also apart from this i have used contentOffSet to hide the button but now the problem is no matter where you scroll (upside/downside) the button is showing up. i want it to restrict only to scroll down

Comment: Try adding the delegate method for `scrollViewDidScroll:`. That will get called on any scrolling so it should be easy for you to test. If that isn't working, chances are your delegate isn't being assigned properly. If it is getting called, you can you it to check your contentOffset for every scroll event and ever reaches 0 point. You can all try the "status bar tap" to force a scroll to the top which should always trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the previous scroll offset so that with each scroll you can compute the delta, telling you whether the user scrolled up or down. With that, you can toggle the button's "hidden" property. Hope that helps.